# Changing background of Primefaces Clock Function

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to change the background of the primefaces clock function. Is there any way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using css. For example:

```
.ui-clock {
    background-color: red;
}
```